# Exclude function from R package manual

Tags: r, documentation, package, roxygen2

I'm writing an R package, and I'm documenting all of my functions with roxygen2. However, I do not want all functions to appear in the manual of the package. **How can I specify which functions should appear in the package manual, or which ones should not?**

I am aware that naming a function with a leading dot, e.g. `.f <- function()` instead of `f <- function()` is a solution. Are there other solutions?

Comment: Why document them if you don't want them in the manual?

Comment: Because it is useful both for me when recalling what functions do, and for others who might want to use the "hidden" functions. I believe I have seen examples in other packages where I could not find the help page of the function by writing `?function_name` in the console after importing the package, but I was able to see the help page if I wrote `?pkgname:::function_name`. I could be remembering wrong though.

Comment: But functions accessed with `:::` are not exported from packages - which typically means the author did not intend for clients to use the function. Generally such functions are not documented - e.g. `tools:::.is_ASCII`. I would guess that if you encountered a non-exported function that *does* have documentation, most likely it was previously an exported (and documented) function, and removed from the list of exports in a later version.

Comment: exported or nonexported functions will have a `man/` document created via roxygen2 if you use the package as designed. The way that I do what you're describing is to not include the quote in the comment so roxygen doesn't pick it up. eg want help file: `#' @param ...` don't want help file `# @param ...` [Here's an example](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/imputeMulti/blob/master/R/int-count_levels.R)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had missed the following detail in the excellent book [R packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) by Hadley Wickham (in the section on object documentation):

> @keywords keyword1 keyword2 ... adds standardised keywords. Keywords are optional, but if present, must be taken from a predefined list found in file.path(R.home("doc"), "KEYWORDS").
>
> Generally, keywords are not that useful except for @keywords internal. **Using the internal keyword removes the function from the package index** and disables some of their automated tests. It’s common to use @keywords internal for functions that are of interest to other developers extending your package, but not most users.

So adding `@keywords internal` to the roxygen2 function documentation results in the function not appearing in the package manual/index, while still making the help page be accessible after loading the package.

Comment: +1 for spotting `@keywords internal.` I don't want to bore people with my internal helper functions, thanks!

Comment: The manual files are getting generated even after the addition of @keywords internal. This is quite annoying when the user tries to search help and all those internal functions too is shown as suggestion. Is there a fix to this?